# How to Convert PDF to Image with Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, image, pdf

I'm managing deposits, where I have a button that visualizes receipts. Vouchers can be attached as images or pdf, only when viewing them they see it from the backend however when viewing this voucher in pdf it is blank. How to convert PDF to Image so I can view? Below is the code and screenshots.

[image]

[image]

Code Modal child TS

```
 public receiptUrl: string = '';

constructor(
    @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: string,
    private readonly matDialogRef: MatDialogRef<FullscreenReceiptComponent>
) { }

public ngOnInit(): void {
    this.verifyWindowDimensions();
    this.matDialogRef.addPanelClass('full-screen-dialog');
    if (this.data) {
        this.receiptUrl = this.data;
    }
}
```

Code Modal child HTML

```
    <mat-icon class="close-icon" mat-dialog-close>close</mat-icon>
    <div class="image" [style.background-image]="'url(\'' + receiptUrl + '\')'">
```

Manage Deposits TS component father
Here I send the data to the child component, to redeem and be able to view the receipt.

```
public openTransferProofDocument(documentUrl: string): string {
    console.log('document', documentUrl)
    return documentUrl;
}

public openFullScreenReceipt(receiptUrl: string): void {
    console.log('receiptUrl', receiptUrl)
    this.dialog.open(FullscreenReceiptComponent, { data: receiptUrl });
}
```

Manage Deposits HTML component father

```
<mat-icon *ngIf="element?.status === status.WAITING"
                            (click)="openFullScreenReceipt(openTransferProofDocument(element?.transferProofFile))"
                            matTooltipClass="tooltip-primary" class="check" [matTooltip]="'manageDeposits.receipt' | translate">receipt</mat-icon>
```

Comment: To convert PDF into image, consider using an imaging library capable of loading and parsing PDF data. One such library is the LEADTOOLS toolkit, which can load, rasterize, and display PDF files. For example, the [RasterCodecs](https://www.leadtools.com/help/sdk/v22/dh/co/rastercodecs.html) class can be implemented in the backend to load the PDF as a raster image which can then be displayed in the modal.